# UITableViewCell with two labels wont center

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView below that has a custom uitableview cell.  I am trying to get the two labels inside it do be 50% in width and have the left cell have right aligned text and the right cell to have left aligned.  Any clue why this isnt working correctly below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use auto-layout, and set both the labels an equal width constraint, it should do the trick.

[image]

**Edit:**
Without auto-layout you can try something like that:
[image: Right label]
[image: Left label]

Comment: Im not doing storyboards, can I do this in interface builder?  I havent added a constraint like that ever, its a five year old project.

Comment: I did the second and it seemed to work, but the text is now centering in the label.  If I get around that Ill mark that as answer.

Comment: Have you checked the alignment modes on each label?

Comment: I figured out the auto layout and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Great! It's true that auto-layout is a real improvement compared to springs and struts!